Rewriting Egyptian Government Protocol?
Rashi (41:12) writes regarding Yosef HaTzaddik:

עֶבֶד. וְכָתוּב בְּנִמּוּסֵי מִצְרַיִם שֶׁאֵין עֶבֶד מוֹלֵךְ וְלֹא
לוֹבֵשׁ בִּגְדֵי שָׂרִים - It is written in Egyptian protocol that a
servant may not rule nor don aristocratic robes.

Since it was against Egyptian government regulations to allow a slave like Yosef to serve in a leadership role, what did Pharaoh do to get around this issue? (e.g., Did they rewrite the protocol? Does marrying a government official's daughter avoid this law?)

How do you know Yosef did either of these prohibited things?

BTW Rashi based this off a midrash in Beresheet Rabbah: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereshit_Rabbah.89.7?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=he. So far I've seen one interpretation of Sakridin being secretarium.

"... what did Pharaoh do to get around this issue?" Was pharaoh actually bound by Egyptian government regulations, for him to have  get around this issue? If he decided to just go ahead with whatever he wanted, who'd oppose him?
